# Split a string on a string not a character

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to split a gridview row on an html tag. How can i do this preferably in C#??

```
e.row.cells[1].Text.Split("htmltag")
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. Use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
String.Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)
```

or

```
String.Split(String[], int, StringSplitOptions)
```

Example:

```
var split = e.row.cells[1].Text.Split(
                new[] { "</b>" },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
            );
```

But do heed StrixVaria's comment above. Parsing HTML is nasty so unless you're an expert offload that work to someone else.

Comment: I get "identifier expected" on the `New []`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to string.split, you can use Regex.Split (in System.Text.RegularExpressions):

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(.row.cells[1].Text, "htmlTag");
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the overloads of `String.Split` takes a `String[]` and a `StringSplitOptions` - this is the overload you want:

```
e.row.cells[1].Text.Split(new string[] { "</b>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or

```
e.row.cells[1].Text.Split(new string[] { "</b>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

depending on what you want done with empty entries (ie when one delimiter immediately follows another).

However, I would urge you to heed @StrixVaria's comment...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Split( new string[] { "</b>" }, StringSplitOptions.None );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those times where I go old school VB and use just use:

```
Split(expression, delimiter)
```

or in C#

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split(expression,delimiter)
```

Answer (score 1):

To split a string with a string, you would use this..

```
string test = "hello::there";
string[] array = test.Split(new string[]{ "::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the overloads of string.Split(...).
But as the comment says, perhaps another method of doing it would be preferrable.

```
e.row.cells[1].Text.Split(new [] { "</b>"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```